# How to edit my theme for full width?

Tags: theme-development, themes, css

I am using Manifest 1.01 by Jim Barraud on my site www.inteftrust.org.

I'd like to know how can I get full width with this theme. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, go to your /wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/style.css and edit the following IDs to look like this:

```
#siteWrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

}

#coreContent{
  float: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#footer{
  width: 97%;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  padding: 20px 0 35px 0;
  border-top: 4px double #ccc;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
}
```

besides that - I see you have some blue image just below this Intef image... I believe one of them is not meant to be there? try this CSS I provided with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) first to see what you'll get... or just play with firebug and see how you can change themes appearance and then apply it to style.css

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. However, the main content body is still of the same width as before. It'd be swell if you can just tell me how to fix that one as well.

Comment: my mistake - make #coreContent width:auto instead of 500px. edited my answer. now it should be fine. (or instead of auto put some percentage...)

Comment: Thanks a tonn. It worked and it was easy. You saved me at least $500 and thought me a new thing.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to edit the css files and adjust width declarations as needed. Consider creating a child theme if you do so.